# context.User.Identity.Name return empty value always in ashx

Tags: asp.net

context.User.Identity.Name return empty value always  in ashx

Login.aspx:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (userName.Text == "admin" && password.Text == "admin")
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName.Text, false, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                Response.Redirect("ManageIndex.aspx");
            }
        }
```

ashx:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for TransactionRecordList
/// </summary>
public class TransactionRecordList : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       string A= context.User.Identity.Name;

    }
```

Comment: Show your web config settings

Comment: @FlopScientist I have solved it,the web.config configure error.TKS!